# missing :00 values from date-time string

Tags: r, macos, datetime, posixct

I have a large date-time series `(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)` that reads as follows:

```
[1] 2009-10-16 00:04:30 2009-10-16 00:04:40 2009-10-16 00:04:50 2009-10-16 00:05   
[5] 2009-10-16 00:05:10 2009-10-16 00:05:20
```

Basically the time increments by 10 secs in each step. However, at the whole minute the `:00` is missing and is causing issues when I convert datetime to `as.POSIXct`. (I get NA).

How can I rectify this?

Comment: you can use a regexp to add the missing 0s or  use a regexp to add the missing 0s `gsub("(.* [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}$)","\\1:00",data)`, if data is your vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just test the length of the string...

```
a <- c("2009-10-16 00:04:30", "2009-10-16 00:04:40", "2009-10-16 00:04:50", "2009-10-16 00:05", "2009-10-16 00:05:10", "2009-10-16 00:05:20")
nchar(a)
[1] 19 19 19 16 19 19
a[nchar(a)==16] <- paste0(a[nchar(a)==16], ":00")
a
[1] "2009-10-16 00:04:30" "2009-10-16 00:04:40" "2009-10-16 00:04:50"
[4] "2009-10-16 00:05:00" "2009-10-16 00:05:10" "2009-10-16 00:05:20"
```

Comment: I think that's the most straight-forward. I sometimes use `sprintf` to insert leading 0's but I've never tried it for trailing characters.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help and speedy reply. Your suggestions solved my issue.